# A simple check if selected, if not add to array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This function is supposed to take the id of the selected row and check to see if it is in an array or not, if it isn't on the array, add it to the array, otherwise remove it from the array. The problem is I can't seem to get the order of events right. The loop does not run all the way through (because of the breaks) but if I remove the breaks, while the image changing (checkbox) works, the array is still wrong.

I also don't understand why despite declaring the `deleteString = [];` outside of this function, without putting it inside the function, the call of `deleteString.push(orderId);` fails

It seems obvious the problem, on the first run regardless of how big the array is, whether or not the check matches or doesn't match, the rest of the loop won't run. So perhaps I should do a check to wait until the loop is done before using the result of found/not-found.

```
function passSelection(orderId) {
  // check if empty
  if (deleteString.length == 0) {
    // turn into array
    deleteString = [];
    // first entry
    deleteString.push(orderId);
    // mark this row as checked
    $("#"+"select-box-"+orderId).attr('src', 'images/red-checked.png');
  }
  else {
    // not the first order
    // check if already in array
    // get length of array
    var delStrLen = deleteString.length;
    // loop through array
    for (var i = 0; i < delStrLen; i++) {
      if (deleteString[i] == orderId) {
        // match found, remove from deleteString array
        deleteString.splice(i, 1);
        // update the row
        $("#"+"select-box-"+orderId).attr('src', 'images/unchecked.png');
        break;
      }
      else {
        // not in the array
        // add to array
        deleteString.push(orderId);
        // update row
        $("#"+"select-box-"+orderId).attr('src', 'images/red-checked.png');
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you can just use indexOf to find if the element is in the array rather than looping all through.

Comment: @dfasoro alright I will try that, I'm looking at MDN's array page, I have seen that but didn't think of using it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ought to use indexOf to test existence of elements in an array.
indexOf returns the position of the search-item or -1 if the element cannot be found
So, here is your code that I have refactored and tested

```
var deleteString = [];
function passSelection(orderId) {
  // check if empty
  let orderPos = deleteString.indexOf(orderId);
  if (orderPos == -1) {
    // first entry
    deleteString.push(orderId);
    // mark this row as checked
    $("#"+"select-box-"+orderId).attr('src', 'images/red-checked.png');
  }
  else {

    // match found, remove from deleteString array
    deleteString.splice(orderPos, 1);
    // update the row
    $("#"+"select-box-"+orderId).attr('src', 'images/unchecked.png');
  }
}
```

Comment: @joehungjohn Please, check my approach too. The problem is that this approach is N times slower (less performant) algorithmically.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly removing the element in for loop is not a good idea as you are manipulating the array which you are traversing. To lookup an item in an array you should use `indexOf` method.

```
function passSelection(orderId) {
  // check if empty
  if (deleteString.length == 0) {
    // turn into array
    deleteString = [];
    // first entry
    deleteString.push(orderId);
    // mark this row as checked
    $("#"+"select-box-"+orderId).attr('src', 'images/red-checked.png');
  }
  else {
    // not the first order
    // check if already in array
    // get length of array
    var delStrLen = deleteString.length;
    // loop through array
    var index = deleteString.indexOf(orderId);
      if (index > -1) {
        // match found, remove from deleteString array
        deleteString.splice(index, 1);
        // update the row
        $("#"+"select-box-"+orderId).attr('src', 'images/unchecked.png');
        break;
      }
      else {
        // not in the array
        // add to array
        deleteString.push(orderId);
        // update row
        $("#"+"select-box-"+orderId).attr('src', 'images/red-checked.png');
        break;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you add your element in a loop. You should check the existence in a loop, and then add / remove your item once. You also do not need a special check for an empty array, your loop will not fire and it will work as expected:

```
function passSelection(orderId) {
    var isFound = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < deleteString.length; i++) {
        if (deleteString[i] == orderId) {
            isFound = true;
        }
    }

    if (isFound) {
        deleteString.splice(i, 1);
        $("#" + "select-box-" + orderId).attr('src', 'images/unchecked.png');
    } else {
        deleteString.push(orderId);
        $("#" + "select-box-" + orderId).attr('src', 'images/red-checked.png');
    }
}
```

Your approach is way too difficult in general. You could simply use `Set` object and achieve this result in a better, more convenient and performant way.
`Set` approach is `O(1)` algorithm, while traversing through your array is `O(N)` algorithm, which means that it can be **thousands times slower.**

```
var set = new Set();
function passSelection(orderId) {
    if (set.has(orderId)) {
        $("#"+"select-box-"+orderId).attr('src', 'images/unchecked.png');
        set.delete(orderId);
    } else { 
        $("#"+"select-box-"+orderId).attr('src', 'images/checked.png');
        set.add(orderId);
    }
}
```

If you need pre-ECMAScript 6 browsers support, then you can utilize object properties in the same way:

```
var set = {};
function passSelection(orderId) {
    if (set[orderId]) {
        $("#"+"select-box-"+orderId).attr('src', 'images/unchecked.png');
        delete set[orderId];
    } else { 
        $("#"+"select-box-"+orderId).attr('src', 'images/checked.png');
        set[orderId] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative approach and cleaner as well, of using objects. It is tough to choose answers. I appreciate your time though and the new method. With javascript/coding in general I don't know when to use objects.

Comment: @joehungjohn It is not about marking answer as correct. It is about taking attention to different approaches and find the most suitable one :)

Comment: It is good to know of the speed, in this case the set may not be larger than a couple sets of ten, but I get your point and will opt for this solution, especially since the code is so much shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you will not need first condition to check if array length is zero. and remove break from else condition. As [dasoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1867130/dfasoro) suggested use indexOf method. instead of loop. Also please try to post a full jsfiddle example so that every one can easily understand your logic. Please see the modified code

```
function passSelection(orderId) {
  if (!deleteString) deleteString = [];

  var index = deleteString.indexOf(orderId);
  if (index !== -1) {
    deleteString.splice(index, 1);
    $("#"+"select-box-"+orderId).attr('src', 'images/unchecked.png');
  } else {
    deleteString.push(orderId);
    $("#"+"select-box-"+orderId).attr('src', 'images/red-checked.png');
}
```

Comment: actually I would have posted console outputs but after switching to i3-wm my key bindings are gone haha so couldn't trigger screenshot ability. I'll keep that in mind next time regarding the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the array to avoid checking whether it exists or not.

```
var arr = [ 4,5,6,1,23 ];
function remove(orderId) {
        var src;
        var index;
        index = arr.indexOf(orderId);
        if (index === -1) {
                arr.push(orderId);
                src = 'images/unchecked.png';
        } else {
                arr.splice(1,index);
                src = 'images/red-checked.png';
        }
        $("#"+"select-box-"+orderId).attr("src",src);
}
// Test item which is in the array (it should be removed)
remove(5);
console.log(arr);
// Test item which is not in the array (it should be added)
remove(24);
console.log(arr);
```